# How to create a list using JQuery and insert objects from a Thymeleaf iterate loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, thymeleaf

I am iterating through following loop for the list of objects "notification" and getting notification id for each notification object as th:text="*{n.id}". I want to insert the list of id's in a list using Jquery.

```
<a  href="#" th:each="n : *{notifications}">
    <h4>
        <span id="notification-id" th:text="*{n.id}"></span>
        <p th:text="*{n.message}"></p>
    </h4>
    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
</a>
```

This is my Jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#notification-href").click(function () {
        $("#notification-count").text('0');
        var notificationId = $("#notification-id");
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me a possible way to do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.Please add more info

Comment: please check now

Comment: I din't understand anything again.I'm sorry.

Comment: You are not allowed to use a static `id` in a loop; an id must be unique in the document.